# .htaccess - Subdomain and path as GET var

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Results to achieve :

```
http://example.com/                   -> /websites/dispatcher.php
http://another-example.com/           -> /websites/dispatcher.php
http://demo.example.com/              -> /websites/dispatcher.php?subdomain=demo
http://demo.example.com/cat/page.html -> /websites/dispatcher.php?subdomain=demo&path=/cat/page.html
```

With the .htaccess i have, it's working except for the "demo.exemple.com" who return a 502 error.

```
# Parse the subdomain as a variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?subdomain=%1

# Map all requests to the 'path' get variable in distpacher.php
RewriteRule ^distpacher\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /distpacher.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm having a hard time... any help, please?

Comment: Change the last RewirteRule from **RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /distpacher.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]** to ***RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /distpacher.php?path=$1 [L,R] **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your 2 rules by these 2 rules:

```
# Map all requests to the 'path' get variable in dispatcher.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dispatcher.php?subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /dispatcher.php?subdomain=%1&path=$1 [L,QSA]
```